# App Crashes after launch screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a big project that was initially running on objective c and now i have converted to swift 2.2 using xcode 7.3 with optimising the code . But the App crashes saying EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.. I know there must be something wrong .. This is the line that is generating

```
 var dict : [NSObject : AnyObject] = userDefaults.objectForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION) as! [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

And same thing is shown here as well

```
 0x10a553f09 <+171>: movq   0xd692d8(%rip), %rbx      ; (void *)0x000000010c04ad70: objc_release
```

Has Anyone got any idea what particularly must have gone wrong ? Let me know If any more information about the code is to be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things that could be wrong with this line:

`userDefaults.objectForKey(mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION) as! [NSObject : AnyObject]`

1. Your `userDefaults` does not actually contain any value for `mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION`
2. You are force casting with `as!`, that might also lead to problems if the contents you get back isn't `[NSObject: AnyObject]`

So you could try to check if your `userDefaults` actually contains a value for `mdmiosagent_Constants.MANAGED_APP_CONFIGURATION`.

If it does, then what the contents? Try not to force cast it for a start and just see what it is.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: If i force cast it , error is like AnyObject? is not convertible to type [NSObject : AnyObject].. so should i declare dict as [Anyobject] ?

Comment: OK, can you set a breakpoint for instance and see what your userDefaults contain?

Comment: And yes, try - just for start - to declare your `dict` as `AnyObject?` (not array, just `AnyObject?`), just so you can set a breakpoint and see what the contents is

Comment: identifier = kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication and container = NULL

Comment: well, I haven't tinkered with this part of the code that was there in objective c .. and it is working fine

Comment: What is `identifier = kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication and container = NULL`? Is that the contents of your `userDefaults`? And if so, does that mean that you have a value of NULL for a key called `kCFPreferencesCurrentApplication`?

Comment: well , that was because i was force casting it into [NSOBject : AnyObject] .. i solved that .. wait. i'll post the screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107110/discussion-between-maneesh-sharma-and-pbodsk).